# Importing CSV file into Android Apps Sqlite data base

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, import

I have a csv file exported from Sqlite browser that contain a table and i have placed it in sdcard . i wish i could import into my android  apps data base programmatically I tried a lot
but failed to achieve any help would be appreciated  . I have the same tabe creatd in android but i dont want to do by reading line by line content from csv file and execute every time query to insert ... so main point is import is directly

hey I have gone through this code

```
public static void InsertCSVFile(String FilePath, String filename,
        String TableName) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("mnt/sdcard/",
                "olinecsv.csv"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String data = "";
        String tableName = "Test";
        String columns = "ID,NAME,TYPE";
        String InsertString1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns
                + ") values(";
        String InsertString2 = ");";

        mainDatabase.beginTransaction();
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(InsertString1);
            String[] sarray = data.split(",");
            sb.append(sarray[0] + ",");
            sb.append( sarray[1] + ",");
            sb.append(sarray[2]);
            sb.append(InsertString2);
            if(sarray[0].contains("ID"))
                continue;
            mainDatabase.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
            //mainDatabase.execSQL(sb.toString());
        }
```

i have place that file in sdcard and i am getting the query StringBuilder but on error or exception are comming and nothing get entered in the table but ,while debugging the same query i ran in Sqlite programs it work 
see i am making and mistake and futher suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Please post your logcat for the exception

Comment: @simon I m nt getting any exception yet but nothing is getting entered

Comment: ok I have found the problem that the line I am using unreasonably mainDatabase.beginTransaction(); removing the line sovled my problem thanks to all for their contribution

Comment: Did you have a matching mainDatabase.endTransaction()? Using begin...end transaction is good practice as it guarantees that either all of your changes are written or none of your changes are written.

Comment: i missed writting mainDatabase.endTransaction() while i wrote mainDatabase.beginTransaction() so my changes was not reflecting .....

Comment: plz see my answer....

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in CSV import function available for you: you will need to read the CSV file line by line and insert it. There are a number of CSV parsing programs (I personally use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)) that will do an excellent job reading from a CSV file on disk and extracting rows. If you have issues writing a valid insert function ask a question and include your code.

Comment: Thanks alright  then what does import mean in sqlite if we have to insert one by one ... one more thing is there any other convinent way to achieve this

Comment: Import is the process of taking data from one storage format (in this case, CSV) and inserting it into another (in this case, your custom SQLite format). The *method* in this case needs to be manually implemented by you, as there is no built-in way to describe how lines in a CSV file are translated into your custom SQLite format on the Android platform.

Comment: actually there is command in sqlite to import CSV file but I don't know if it exist in any of the libraries. `sqlite> create table test (id integer, datatype_id integer, level integer, meaning text);`
`sqlite> .separator ","`
`sqlite> .import no_yes.csv test` [link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

create a folder in res>raw and put your yourfile.csv file in raw folder.

Add this methos to insert data in sqlite,

```
  public void insertCSVData(Activity activity, InputStream is, String tableName) {

    String colunmNames = null, str1 = null;
    open();

    try {

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = "";

        String str2 = ");";

        db.beginTransaction();

        int i = 0;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            if (i == 1) {
                colunmNames = line;
                str1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + colunmNames + ") values (";
            } else {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
                String[] str = line.split(",");

                for (int h = 0; h < str.length; h++) {

                    if (h == str.length - 1) {
                        sb.append("'" + str[h] + "'");
                    } else {
                        sb.append("'" + str[h] + "',");
                    }
                }

                sb.append(str2);
                db.execSQL(sb.toString());
            }
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        close();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    close();
}
   public void open() {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
}
```

Call this Method by

```
insertCSVData(Activity, getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile.csv), tableName);
```

I wish this code solve your problem...

Comment: can you tell me what are you doing in Open(),

Comment: @Sathish In open and close i m opening and closing database.